# The difference between Faiss Index and a Database Index

Tags: indexing, data-indexing-techniques

An index points to data in a table. In a database, indexes are similar to those in books. I am a little bit confused about the meaning of index in Faiss library and how it's different from the one in the database please if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR;

FAISS Indexation is done over an encoding of the vectors and it is used for *similarity search*. Whereas, traditional database indexation is done for *exact lookups*.

## FAISS

Purpose: to efficiently find the most similar high-demension vector from the input vector. Typically for machine learning purposes. A perfect match is not mandatory.

Method:

1. Encoding the vectors. Assuming each dimension is stored in a separate field or column, we bring them together into a single field. Even a dimensionality reduction is possible, but that has to be balanced with any loss of information.
2. Building the index. This is done over the encoded vector and methods can be similar to traditional db indexation.
3. Querying. Traditional db look ups will look for exact matches in the index, but with FAISS, a similarity metric (e.g. cosine similarity) is used to find the best matches.